# How to determine if base64 and unicode character are equivalent?

Tags: unicode, encoding, google-bigquery, base64, byte

I'm trying to figure out if the two encodings of the character are the same:

```
SELECT 
    ~b"1", 
    code_points_to_string([0x380]), 
    "\u0380"
```

The first is base64-encoded and the second is a string. How can I determine if these are equivalent? Is there some sort of function where I can, for example extract the code point from a base64-string in BigQuery?

[image]

Comment: `'zg=='` decodes to the single byte `CE`, which is the first byte in the two-byte UTF-8-encoded sequence (`CE 80`) for U+0380.  According to the Unicode 15.0 [code chart](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf), U+0380 is not defined.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks, how did you find out (that is, what tool did you use) to see that `zg==` decodes to `CE` ?

Comment: I used Python, with `base64.b64decode('zg==')`, but you can use [this online decoder](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/base64-decode.html) as well.

Comment: @David542 Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @kiran -- of course, a sql answer on BQ would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned ~b"1"  as `base64-encoded` but according to this [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#bitwise_operators)  `~ X` is a Bitwise not operator. Here you are converting the string value to bytes and then performing Bitwise Not operation on it (Though while showing in UI BQ shows in base64 encoded).  To convert it into `base64-encoded` you can use the `TO_BASE64` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#to_base64).

You can use the `to_code_points` function to extract the code points from a base 64 encoded string.

```
select *
,from_base64(d) decoded_val_bytes
,SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(from_base64(d)) sring_value
,to_code_points(from_base64(d)) cp
from (
 select
 ~b"foo" a,
 code_points_to_string([102,111,111]) b
 ,to_base64(b"foo") d
 ,to_code_points("foo") e
)
```

`to_code_points` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#to_code_points) is to convert string or bytes into an array of INT64 and `code_points_to_string` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#code_points_to_string) is to convert an array of INT64  into  STRING.